# Cakephp get details about security component error

Tags: security, cakephp

I am using security component in my projects and is there any way to get the detailed description about the error while developing ? For ex:- if any field is added in view without using cakephp's form method, it is returning error as 'auth' in my blackHoleCallback function. Instead I need beacuse of what reason it returned that error. Because it is taking so much time to rectify the problem. Is there any way to get the detailed error description ?

Comment: Usually the stack trace should give you a good idea where to look for the problem. It should throw that when in debug mode.

Comment: The answers below provide a lot of good tips... but before you dive into them, check one thing: Did you include the create and end statements for the form? Sometimes I replace the `echo $this->Form->end('Submit');` with a `echo $this->Form->submit('Submit',array());` so that I can apply a class to the button, and then I forget to add an empty `echo $this->Form->end();` after it. This leads to a black hole error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is look in the right place

### Check your `app/tmp/logs/error.log` file

If you look in the error log you'll see an entry like this:

```
2013-03-16 17:24:29 Error: [BadRequestException] The request has been black-holed
#0 root/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php(228): SecurityComponent->blackHole(Object(FacebookUsersController), 'csrf')
#1 [internal function]: SecurityComponent->startup(Object(FacebookUsersController))
#2 root/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php(130): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: ObjectCollection->trigger(Object(CakeEvent))
#4 root/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(246): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
#5 root/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(670): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
#6 root/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(183): Controller->startupProcess()
#7 root/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(161): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(FacebookUsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#8 root/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
```

### Read the error that is on screen

If you are in debug mode, this error is also shown on screen when the error happens. e.g.:

```
The request has been black-holed
Error: The requested address '/admin/fooby/edit/1' was not found on this server.

Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php line 228 → SecurityComponent->blackHole(FacebookUsersController, string)
[internal function] → SecurityComponent->startup(FacebookUsersController)
CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php line 130 → call_user_func_array(array, array)
[internal function] → ObjectCollection->trigger(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 246 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 670 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 183 → Controller->startupProcess()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 161 → Dispatcher->_invoke(FacebookUsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 96 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

### Handling csrf errors

With the *details* of a *specific* error (i.e. the data you are posting, and the exact token data in your session at the time) it would be possible to answer what problem brought you here, in the absense of that:

#### *look* at the line throwing the error.

In the stack trace above, the error is coming from `CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php line 228` - Open the file and look what that code is:

```
if ($isPost && $isNotRequestAction && $this->csrfCheck) {
    if ($this->_validateCsrf($controller) === false) {
        return $this->blackHole($controller, 'csrf');
    }   
}
```

What should be obvious from this is that the function `_validateCsrf` is responsible for the request being blackholed. This should not really be much of a surprise.

*Look* at the source of that function:

```
protected function _validateCsrf(Controller $controller) {
    $token = $this->Session->read('_Token');
    $requestToken = $controller->request->data('_Token.key');
    if (isset($token['csrfTokens'][$requestToken]) && $token['csrfTokens'][$requestToken] >= time()) {
        if ($this->csrfUseOnce) {
            $this->Session->delete('_Token.csrfTokens.' . $requestToken);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Depending on why that function returns false, determines how you continue to debug.

#### Correct configuration of the component

The inevitable consequence of debugging a CSRF error is you'll need to modify the [configuration of the Security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-configuration).

Do you, for example, want to be reusing tokens, because your app is submitting the same form multiple times between page loads?

Are you self-invalidating the form requests by adding new fields to the form data - You can use [the unlockedFields property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::$unlockedFields) to exclude these fields from the csrf checks.

You can also simply [disable CSRF checks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-the-csrf-protection) completey. That has obvious security consequences - but if you're struggling to work with the component, it's an easy way to work around and problems you currently face.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im not feeling difficulty in using this, sometimes taking time to solve the issue.

Comment: Andy how are you getting so much detail in your error.log file? Security component isn't logging to that at all for me regardless of debug level.

Answer (score 3):

In order to see the mechanisms I dug into the code to see how the FormHelper hash is created vs. how the SecurityComponent validation checks the hash.  Here's how to see exactly what is happening behind the scenes.

**Checking the input to the FormHelper.**  Open CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php.  In the secure() function add some pr lines around the $files=Security::hash line to see how the tokens are built:

```
pr($fields);//hashed into computed token on next line
$fields = Security::hash(serialize($fields) . $unlocked . Configure::read('Security.salt'), 'sha1');
pr($unlocked); //hashed into computed token
pr(Configure::read('Security.salt')); //hashed into computed token
pr($fields); //computed token passed via hidden token field in form
```

**Check how form is processed**
Now check how the submitted form is processed and compared to the passed token:
Open the CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php.  Insert some pr lines in the _validatePost() routine at the end:

```
pr($fieldList); //hashed into computed token
pr($unlocked); //hashed into computed token
pr(Configure::read('Security.salt')); //hashed into computed token
pr($token); //passed token from FormHelper
pr($check); //computed token
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who has problems with locked/unlocked or missing fields quickly figure out what is going on inside of your cake.

Answer (score 1):

Remember also that you have to have an exact match between the `Token` generated by the `FormHelper` and that retrieved bu cake using Session. The mismatch can happen, as the doc says, when you dynamically generate input or when make ajax call: remember to serialize the form and submit it via ajax!

If you have input tag generated not generated by using the `FormHelper`, you have to unlock'em. For example in your `beforeFilter()`:

```
$this->Security->unlockedFields = 
                 array('MyModel.some_field1','MyModel.some_field2')
```

where `field1` and `field2` are fields generated "by hand", i.e. by not using the Helper.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: "Is there any way to get the detailed error description?"

First thing is to add more valuable debugging to your controller when it comes to SecurityComponent.  Here's one way to do it:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    //your beforeFilter code

    //Enable CSRF and other protections
    $this->Security->csrfExpires = '+1 hour';
    $this->Security->csrfUseOnce = true;
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
}

public function blackhole($errorType) {

    $errorMap['auth']   = 'form validation error, or a controller/action mismatch error.';
    $errorMap['csrf']   = 'CSRF error.';
    $errorMap['get']    = 'HTTP method restriction failure.';
    $errorMap['post']   = $errorMap['get'];
    $errorMap['put']    = $errorMap['get'];
    $errorMap['delete'] = $errorMap['get'];
    $errorMap['secure'] = 'SSL method restriction failure.';
    $errorMap['myMoreValuableErrorType']    = 'My custom and very ' . 
    'specific reason for the error type.';

    CakeLog::notice("Request to the '{$this->request->params['action']}' " . 
"endpoint was blackholed by SecurityComponent due to a {$errorMap[$errorType]}");
}
```

As AD7six mentioned take a look at the `CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php`.  Specifically `SecurityComponent::startup()`.  In that method you will notice that `SecurityComponent::blackhole()` method is ran a few times.  It's ran whenever the criteria fails a security check and looks like this:

```
return $this->blackHole($controller, 'auth');
```

In this case 'auth' represents the type of security check that failed.  You could customize the 'auth' string to be more valuable.  For example instead of 'auth' use 'myMoreValuableErrorType' and then map that to something more meaningful.

So instead of running `$this->blackHole($controller, 'auth')` when a security check fails, you would run `$this->blackHole($controller, 'myMoreValuableErrorType')` and then map 'myMoreValuableErrorType' to a specific reason on why it failed by using the code above.